# How can I change the width and height of this SVG without breaking it?

Tags: css, svg

I have this SVG and I want to make it bigger in height or/and width but to look exactly the same in consistency:

```html
<svg width="104" height="102" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M104 102V59.727H84.114c0-5.871.689-11.182 2.068-15.933 1.379-4.75 3.42-9.287 6.125-13.61C95.01 25.86 98.909 22.257 104 19.375V0c-9.758 4.27-17.712 9.874-23.864 16.813-6.151 6.939-10.712 14.545-13.681 22.818C63.485 47.904 62 59.941 62 75.74V102h42zm-62 0V59.727H22.114c0-5.871.689-11.182 2.068-15.933 1.379-4.75 3.42-9.287 6.125-13.61C33.01 25.86 36.909 22.257 42 19.375V0c-9.652 4.27-17.58 9.874-23.784 16.813C12.01 23.752 7.424 31.358 4.455 39.631 1.485 47.904 0 59.941 0 75.74V102h42z" fill="#A775F1" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
</svg>
```

And it doesn't make any difference in the size if I make the width and the height a larger number (from 104x102 to 416x408):

```html
<svg width="416" height="408" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M104 102V59.727H84.114c0-5.871.689-11.182 2.068-15.933 1.379-4.75 3.42-9.287 6.125-13.61C95.01 25.86 98.909 22.257 104 19.375V0c-9.758 4.27-17.712 9.874-23.864 16.813-6.151 6.939-10.712 14.545-13.681 22.818C63.485 47.904 62 59.941 62 75.74V102h42zm-62 0V59.727H22.114c0-5.871.689-11.182 2.068-15.933 1.379-4.75 3.42-9.287 6.125-13.61C33.01 25.86 36.909 22.257 42 19.375V0c-9.652 4.27-17.58 9.874-23.784 16.813C12.01 23.752 7.424 31.358 4.455 39.631 1.485 47.904 0 59.941 0 75.74V102h42z" fill="#A775F1" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: How you display this?

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? And what do you mean by "look exactly the same in consistency"?

Comment: I mean it looks deformed when I try to give it a height of 9.4rem and a width of 9rem. my rem value is 1rem= 10 px;

Comment: it looks like this https://imgur.com/JBc7Phf 

Comment: For a start, remove the width/height and use a proper `viewbox`. Other than that, unable to reproduce - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xxXJyEW

Answer (score 2):

It is often a good idea to use the [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute on `<svg>`. It defines the inner dimensions of the SVG.

In the examples I removed the width and height attributes, set the viewBox and define the height or width using CSS. Without defining the height or width (only viewBox), the SVG will take up 100 % of the available width.

```css
svg:nth-child(1) {
  height: 20px;
}

svg:nth-child(2) {
  height: 5em;
}

svg:nth-child(3) {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 104 102" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M104 102V59.727H84.114c0-5.871.689-11.182 2.068-15.933 1.379-4.75 3.42-9.287 6.125-13.61C95.01 25.86 98.909 22.257 104 19.375V0c-9.758 4.27-17.712 9.874-23.864 16.813-6.151 6.939-10.712 14.545-13.681 22.818C63.485 47.904 62 59.941 62 75.74V102h42zm-62 0V59.727H22.114c0-5.871.689-11.182 2.068-15.933 1.379-4.75 3.42-9.287 6.125-13.61C33.01 25.86 36.909 22.257 42 19.375V0c-9.652 4.27-17.58 9.874-23.784 16.813C12.01 23.752 7.424 31.358 4.455 39.631 1.485 47.904 0 59.941 0 75.74V102h42z" fill="#A775F1" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 104 102" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M104 102V59.727H84.114c0-5.871.689-11.182 2.068-15.933 1.379-4.75 3.42-9.287 6.125-13.61C95.01 25.86 98.909 22.257 104 19.375V0c-9.758 4.27-17.712 9.874-23.864 16.813-6.151 6.939-10.712 14.545-13.681 22.818C63.485 47.904 62 59.941 62 75.74V102h42zm-62 0V59.727H22.114c0-5.871.689-11.182 2.068-15.933 1.379-4.75 3.42-9.287 6.125-13.61C33.01 25.86 36.909 22.257 42 19.375V0c-9.652 4.27-17.58 9.874-23.784 16.813C12.01 23.752 7.424 31.358 4.455 39.631 1.485 47.904 0 59.941 0 75.74V102h42z" fill="#A775F1" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 104 102" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M104 102V59.727H84.114c0-5.871.689-11.182 2.068-15.933 1.379-4.75 3.42-9.287 6.125-13.61C95.01 25.86 98.909 22.257 104 19.375V0c-9.758 4.27-17.712 9.874-23.864 16.813-6.151 6.939-10.712 14.545-13.681 22.818C63.485 47.904 62 59.941 62 75.74V102h42zm-62 0V59.727H22.114c0-5.871.689-11.182 2.068-15.933 1.379-4.75 3.42-9.287 6.125-13.61C33.01 25.86 36.909 22.257 42 19.375V0c-9.652 4.27-17.58 9.874-23.784 16.813C12.01 23.752 7.424 31.358 4.455 39.631 1.485 47.904 0 59.941 0 75.74V102h42z" fill="#A775F1" fill-rule="nonzero"/>
</svg>
```